# Mongoose Query (Regex) (MongoDB & NodeJS)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I would like to know how can I change the Regex to **/^email.*/**

I'm having difficulties, could you help me?

```
// Retrieve all apis from the database.
exports.findAllPasswords = (req, res) => {
  const password = req.query.password;
  var condition = password ? { password: { $regex: new RegExp(password), $options: "i" } } : {};
  if (!password)
  res.json({ message: "Password param missing!" });

  api.find(condition)
    .then(data => {
    res.send(data);
    })
    .catch(err => {
      res.status(500).send({
        message:
          err.message || "Some error occurred while retrieving apis."
      });
    });
};
```

Comment: Hi there, can you be more specific about what the problem is? Changing the regex doesn't sound like a problem, perhaps, the query is not behaving the way you expect, is that it? If the issue is understanding the regex query to modify it, you can take a look at [this](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/index.html)

Comment: Do you just mean `new RegExp('^' + password)`? I'm not understanding your actual question.

Comment: No, my problem isn't with "Regex", my problema is a very slow query.